# What is the granularity of "masked" stores in AVX512?

Tags: performance, assembly, intel, cpu-architecture, avx512

Lets say you call **_mm512_mask_store_ps**, from the point of view of the CPU's write buffer, is it executed as a store of *size 64-bytes* (with some sort of masking) or is it executed internally as multiple stores of *size 4-bytes*?

In order to prevent **store-to-load forwarding stalls**, one must match the granularity (size) of a store to the granularity of subsequent loads to the same memory location.
Hopefully the question makes sense, I'm no CPU architecture expert.

Comment: See [§11.9 CONDITIONAL SIMD PACKED LOADS AND STORES](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf).

Answer (score 6):

As Iwillnotexist referenced:

> If the mask is not all 1 or all 0, loads that depend on the masked
> store have to wait until the store data is written to the cache. If
> the mask is all 1 the data can be forwarded from the masked store to
> the dependent loads. If the mask is all 0 the loads do not depend on
> the masked store.

So there's no store-to-load forwarding for masked-stores, except for the case when the mask is all ones (behaves like a regular store), or all zeros (trivial).
Load after a masked-store generally waits for data to be sent to cache, so it should be pretty expensive.

Comment: Using scatter-gather to do multiple hashmap-counter updates in parallel is sounding like more and more of a fool's errand, between this and the difficulties of efficiently handling collisions...